# how can I make it that the list updates itself?

Tags: python, web-scraping

In every "for" loop, two items (user and likes) are taken from the "Data" list and are added to a separate list (scoreboard). I am trying to detect if "user" already exists in the scoreboard list. If it does exist, then I try to take the item that comes after "user" in the scoreboard list (which would be the previous "likes" item) and add the new "likes" item to it, after that I try to set the new "likes" item to the new value. but i couldn't make it work.

```
   def likecount():
        scoreboard = []
        for t in range(0,len(Data),3):
            user = Data[t]
            likes = Data[t + 2]
            if user not in scoreboard:
                scoreboard.append(user), scoreboard.append(likes)
            else:
                scoreboard[(scoreboard.index(user) + 1)] + likes == scoreboard[(scoreboard.index(user) + 1)]
                
                    
        for i in range(0,len(scoreboard),2):
            print (scoreboard[i],scoreboard[i+1], end= "\n")
```

#Data list:

```
['Rhett_andEmma77', 'Los Angeles is soooo hot', '0', 'Tato', 'Glitch', '1', 'Aurio', 'April fools tomorrow', '4', 'nap', 'The bully**', '3', 'NICKSION', 'Oops', '6', 'stupidfuck', 'hes a little guy', '5', 'database', 'Ty', '1', 'stupidfuck', 'possible object show (objects needed)', '3', 'NightSkyMusic', 'nicotine takes 10 seconds to reach your brain', '27', 'stupidfuck', '@BFBleafyfan99 be   anii e', '4', 'Odminey', 'Aliveness', '26', 'stupidfuck', '@techness2011 the', '5', 'techness2011', 'Boomerang', '1', 'saltyipaint', 'April is r slur month', '5', 'HENRYFOLIO', 'flip and dunk', '4', 'SpenceAnimation', 'Got Any grapes ', '2', 'RainyFox2', 'Draw me in your style****', '1', 'hecksacontagon', 'funky cat guy impresses you with his fish corpse', '11', 'HENRYFOLIO', 'flip and dunk @bruhkeko version', '4', 'nairb', 'Spoderman turns green', '5', 'SpenceAnimation', 'Jellybean', '1', 'SpenceAnimation', '@FussiArt', '3']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictiionary is precisely the thing you are looking for instead of keeping a list of items. So whenever a user is considered, you will check if he/she exists

1. If exists, then add the new likes to the old like count.
2. If it doesn't, create an entry with the like count.

That is the natural solution.

```
data = ['Rhett_andEmma77', 'Los Angeles is soooo hot', '0', 'Tato', 'Glitch', '1', 'Aurio', 'April fools tomorrow', '4', 'nap', 'The bully**', '3', 'NICKSION', 'Oops', '6', 'stupidfuck', 'hes a little guy', '5', 'database', 'Ty', '1', 'stupidfuck', 'possible object show (objects needed)', '3', 'NightSkyMusic', 'nicotine takes 10 seconds to reach your brain', '27', 'stupidfuck', '@BFBleafyfan99 be   anii e', '4', 'Odminey', 'Aliveness', '26', 'stupidfuck', '@techness2011 the', '5', 'techness2011', 'Boomerang', '1', 'saltyipaint', 'April is r slur month', '5', 'HENRYFOLIO', 'flip and dunk', '4', 'SpenceAnimation', 'Got Any grapes ', '2', 'RainyFox2', 'Draw me in your style****', '1', 'hecksacontagon', 'funky cat guy impresses you with his fish corpse', '11', 'HENRYFOLIO', 'flip and dunk @bruhkeko version', '4', 'nairb', 'Spoderman turns green', '5', 'SpenceAnimation', 'Jellybean', '1', 'SpenceAnimation', '@FussiArt', '3']
assert(len(data)%3 == 0)
scoreboard = {}
for i in range(0, len(data), 3):
    if data[i] in scoreboard.keys():
        scoreboard[data[i]]+= int(data[i+2])
    else:
        scoreboard[data[i]] = int(data[i+2])

print(scoreboard)
```

##### Output

```
    {'Rhett_andEmma77': 0, 'Tato': 1, 'Aurio': 4, 'nap': 3, 'NICKSION': 6, 'stupidfuck': 17, 'database': 1, 'NightSkyMusic': 27, 'Odminey': 26, 'techness2011': 1, 'saltyipaint': 5, 'HENRYFOLIO': 8, 'SpenceAnimation': 6, 'RainyFox2': 1, 'hecksacontagon': 11, 'nairb': 5}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but the data list I use is filled by web scraping data, and when I tried to use dictionaries earlier it would create some problems since you can only keep two sets of data in dictionaries however what I am taking from the websites are a larger variety of data, so I would need to sacrifice other kinds of data in order to use dictionaries.

Comment: @idontusefolioscope.: What do you mean? You can create your own class to store the data in dictionary where the key would be the `name` just like here. It would work. So that mean `dictionary['abc']=some object containing everything`

Comment: Oh I think I understand, I will try the code you provided, thank you so much!